# blanching slightly frozen fresh garden carrots

Tags: blanching

I searched online to see if a person could still blanch slightly frozen carrots, but nothing seems to give me a straight answer. Get a lot on how to blanch them, and that I can freeze fresh carrots, but nothing in regards to if it is possible. Hopefully someone can give me some answers and advice. Thanks

Comment: If they're your carrots, and you've got a bit of room, next time, try [clamping](https://www.gardenersworld.com/how-to/grow-plants/how-to-store-carrots/) them instead.

Answer (score 1):

freezing and thawing will break cells and make the carrots (in that case) a little bit mushy.

Other than that, blanch away; I don't see any problems with that.